# Firebase Syntax - Query Children

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

What is the syntax to query this Firebase data structure? I want to aggregate (sum) carAmount where carNames are the same.

[image]

To start, I cannot figure out how to get to carName. For now just logging the answer to LogCat is good enough.  Here is my code:

```
   FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    final DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("apo");

    myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String carName = (String) child.child("carName").getValue();
                Log.d( "fb_util "," val " + carName);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your database is really nested.. check out this link to first of organize your data a bit better https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data

Comment: Your `for` loop is still in date (`2016-12-22`, etc) level, still need one level more deep, like putting this inside your for loop `for(DataSnapshot childChild: child.getChildren()) {`. But I you should also consider @hotrod 's solution, as I also think your database is too deep.

Comment: Thanks guys. I appreciate the help.  I agree. I will  flatten the database but I want to keep the data. I know there is an export and import in the browser based Firebase UI but when I export I will have to "re-arrange" records in the exported JSON file to achieve flattening before I re-import to a new more flat structure in FB. Please recommend a way to do this. There are appro 32 additional fields at the carAmount, carName level. Some are nested 2 layers. There are about 50-70 distinct keys (just below the date/above carAmount). So how do I "Recode" these JSON records easily?